# How does bitshifting to the left by 3 gives you the number of bits in bytes?

Tags: c++, c, bit

I'm learning about bit packing and bit buffers and I came across this line of code

```
int NumBits = sizeof(float) << 3
```

now the output is correct, a float is 4 bytes and when  you convert that to bits it's 32 bits, which is the value of `NumBits`

my question is how did bit shifting to the left by 3 give us the correct value ?

also they could do it in the opposite way, by shifting the actual `NumBits` to the right by 3

```
int numbytes = NumBits >> 3;
```

Comment: read that `<< 3` as  ` * 8` . As the answer below mentions, left shifting an integer to the right by n bits is equivalent to multiplying by 2^n

Comment: That's a little non-portable.  If you work on a platform that has a different bits-per-byte ratio (like a DS9K, or the 13-bit/byte machine I worked on at the U of MN), the math doesn't work out.  Instead it should be `int NumBits = sizeof(float) * CHAR_BIT;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sizeof(float) returns the size of a float in bytes. In most systems(e.g. PC), a float is 4 bytes, so sizeof(float) is equal to 4.

The << operator is the left shift operator. When you left-shift a value by a certain number of bits, you effectively multiply the value by 2 raised to the power of the number of bits shifted. In this case, you are left-shifting by 3 bits, so it's equivalent to multiplying by 2^3, which is 8.

So, sizeof(float) << 3 is equivalent to 4 << 3, which is equal to 32.

In summary, shifting to the left by 3 is same as multiplying with 8, which gives the number of bits. Likewise, shifting to the right by 3 is same as dividing to 8.

Comment: So, why did they convert it using bit shifting instead of normal multiplication and division ? does bit shifting perform better on the cpu ?

Comment: @noob-cryptor don't do this type of thing, write out the multiplication. The compiler most likely will transform it into a shift, but in the source code write it out clearly. there's no reason to do that here other than teaching about shift <-> multiplication operation equivalence.

Comment: @Ait-GacemNabil Thank you, I got confused because that code was from an actual video game that is live right now and I was wondering why they did it this way

Comment: CPUs can directly perform bit shifting so there are assembly instructions for them. Languages like C, support bit-shifting for low level programming.

Comment: Bit-shifting is primarily used when you want to multiply or divide by powers of 2, which is a specialized and efficient operation, or when you need to manipulate individual bits within data.
For general arithmetic operations involving non-power-of-2 factors, you would typically use standard arithmetic operators like * for multiplication and / for division. These operators are designed to handle arbitrary arithmetic and are more suitable for such purposes. Bit-shifting is not a replacement for general arithmetic; it's a specialized tool for specific scenarios.

Comment: @CemPolat use `*` as  you need to multiply by `CHAR_BIT` to get the portable result

Comment: @noob-cryptor - Some programmers just try to be too clever, especially when trying to show off in a video.  :-) I bet their game will not work anyway on systems where `float` is not 32 bits.

Answer (score 2):

```
int NumBits = sizeof(float) << 3
```

It might give yuo the correct number on systems where `char` is 8 bits long. But  the portable way is:

```
int NumBits = sizeof(float) * CHAR_BIT;
```

Comment: ... and remember to `#include <limits.h>`